# Stop function on mouseleave

Tags: jquery, foreach, mouseleave

I am having issues with a function that is trigger on mouseenter and it loops. The problem is that I want to function to stop on mouseleave.

Tried a few things but nothing seemed to work as expected.

HTML

```
<div class="trigger">Hover me to trigger animation</div>

<div class="logo-tagline">
  <span>Simple.</span>
  <span>Fast.</span>
  <span>Around you.</span>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$( ".trigger" ).mouseenter(function() {
  function highlight(items, index) {
    index = index % items.length;
    items.removeClass("-visible");
    items.eq(index).addClass('-visible');   
    setTimeout(function() {
      highlight(items, index + 1)
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  highlight($('.logo-tagline span'), 0);
});
```

Link to my pen: https://codepen.io/Vlasin/pen/YzZxqNp?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you just need to clear the `setTimeout`, something as following
- Note though that depending upon whether or not you want to hide the text again is up to you so handle that accordingly.

  ```
    let timeoutFunc;
    function highlight(items, index) {
        index = index % items.length;
        items.removeClass("-visible");
        items.eq(index).addClass('-visible');   
        timeoutFunc = setTimeout(function() {
            highlight(items, index + 1)
        }, 1000);
    }

    $( ".trigger" ).mouseenter(function() {
        highlight($('.logo-tagline span'), 0);
    });

    $( ".trigger" ).mouseleave(function() {
        $('.-visible').removeClass("-visible");
        clearTimeout(timeoutFunc);
    });
  ```

Comment: Can you help me with removing the "-visible" class on mouseleave?

Answer (score 0):

check this working example:
https://codepen.io/DibashSapkota/pen/YzZxrXw?editors=0010

```
$( ".trigger" ).mouseenter(startInterval);
$( ".trigger" ).mouseleave(stopInterval);

// You'll need a variable to store a reference to the timer
var timer = null;

function startInterval() {

  /* Your Function Code HERE */

  // Then you initilize the variable
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Foo Executed!");
  }, 1500);
}

function stopInterval() {
  // To cancel an interval, pass the timer to clearInterval()
  clearInterval(timer);
}
```